# Ironpython script for reverse sort order date + has to select latest date from column (filter type: Listbox) in Spotfire 7.8?

Tags: python, ironpython, spotfire

I am looking for Ironpython script that can help me reverse, sort, and order date column from report/data flow in spotfire 7.8v, & it has to select the latest date/current date in the column (filter type: Listbox) within text area visualization.

Here's what i have tried to reverse sort dates but this doesn't help to select latest date (may be a little tweak somewhere in the script below needed i guess). If not please provide new script resolves this issue.

IRONPython SCRIPT:

```
from System.Reflection import Assembly

from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Collections import *

from System.Runtime.Serialization import ISerializable

from System.Collections import IComparer

from System.Collections.Generic import IComparer

column = Document.Data.Tables['DATA_TABLE'].Columns['COLUMN_NAME']

values = column.RowValues.GetEnumerator()

myValues = []

for val in values:

    if val.HasValidValue:  #exclude empty values

        myValues.Add(val.ValidValue)

myValues.sort(reverse=True)

column.Properties.SetCustomSortOrder(myValues)
```

Thanks
Maddy

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer to my question hope this helps for other users as well. Please find below Iron python script for reverse sort date order(descending order) that has to select latest date in list box filter.

```
from System.Reflection import Assembly
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Collections import *


from System.Runtime.Serialization import ISerializable`
from System.Collections import IComparer
from System.Collections.Generic import IComparer
from System.Collections.Generic import IComparer
```

column = Document.Data.Tables['TABLE_NAME'].Columns['COLUMN_NAME']

```
values = column.RowValues.GetEnumerator()
#Val is a value inside the Column specified in the GetFilter
#print values
myValues = []
for Val in values:
if Val.HasValidValue:  #exclude empty values
myValues.Add(Val.ValidValue)
print Val.ValidValue
myValues.sort(reverse=True)
column.Properties.SetCustomSortOrder(myValues)
myPanel = Document.ActivePageReference.FilterPanel
myFilter= myPanel.TableGroups[0].GetFilter("COLUMN_NAME")
#ListBoxFilter
#myFilter.FilterReference.TypeId = FilterTypeIdentifiers.ListBoxFilter
listBoxFilter = myFilter.FilterReference.As[filters.ListBoxFilter]()
listBoxFilter.IncludeAllValues=False
listBoxFilter.SetSelection(myValues[0])
#uncheck all
#ListBoxFilter.IncludeEmpty = False #make sure to clear the empty values
#for value in ListBoxFilter.Values:
#  ListBoxFilter.Uncheck(value)
#ListBoxFilter.Check(myValues)
```